# C++ CMake ..\lib\tgbot.lib deprecated to ..\lib

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to add a `TgBot.lib` file to CMakeLists.txt using `target_link_libraries()`. The file path is ProjectRoot\dependencies\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\TgBot.lib. CMake gives me an error

```
Target "executable" requests linking to directory
1> [CMake]   "D:/Programming/C++/Projects/Project/dependencies/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib".
1> [CMake]   Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item
```

I used the CMake instructions from `https://github.com/reo7sp/tgbot-cpp/blob/master/samples/echobot/CMakeLists.txt`.
The CMake file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)
project(SpotifyBotCMake CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall")
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)

file(GLOB_RECURSE headerFiles "/${CMAKE_PROJECT_DIR}SpotifyBot/*.h")
file(GLOB_RECURSE sourceFiles "/${CMAKE_PROJECT_DIR}SpotifyBot/*.cpp")

set(BOOST_ROOT "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/boost_1_81_0")
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/boost_1_81_0")

find_package(Boost)
find_package(boost_filesystem)
find_package(boost_system)
find_package(boost_date_time)

set(BUILD_TESTING OFF)
set(BUILD_TESTING_STATIC OFF)
set(BUILD_TESTING_SHARED OFF)

file (GLOB_RECURSE sources CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "SpotifyBot/*.cpp")
file (GLOB_RECURSE headers CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "SpotifyBot/*.h")

set (includeDir "SpotifyBot")

foreach (_headerFile ${headers})
    get_filename_component(_dir ${_headerFile} PATH)
    list (APPEND includeDir ${_dir})
endforeach()
list (REMOVE_DUPLICATES includeDir)

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)

find_package(jsoncpp)
set(JSONCPP_LIBRARY_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib")
link_directories(${JSONCPP_LIBRARY_DIR})

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/curl")
set(CURL_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/curl/include")
include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIR})
set(CURL_LIBRARY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib")

set(CURL_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/curl)

find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
add_library(curl STATIC IMPORTED)

include_directories(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

if (CURL_FOUND)
    include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    add_definitions(-DHAVE_CURL)
endif()

set(VCPKG_INSTALLATION_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows")


set(TGBOT_LIBRARY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/TgBot.lib")

file(GLOB_RECURSE headerFiles "/${CMAKE_PROJECT_DIR}SpotifyBot/*.h")
file(GLOB_RECURSE sourceFiles "/${CMAKE_PROJECT_DIR}SpotifyBot/*.cpp")

set(CMAKE_THREAD_PREFER_PTHREAD TRUE) # these are to use the prefered -pthread flag
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG TRUE) # over the -lpthread option
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

add_executable(executable SpotifyBot/main.cpp SpotifyBot/server.cpp SpotifyBot/jsonHandler.cpp SpotifyBot/SpotifyAPIHandler.cpp SpotifyBot/config.cpp)

target_include_directories(
    executable PUBLIC 
    "dependencies/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include" 
    ${includeDir} 
    ${headerFiles} 
    #${TGBOT_LIBRARY_DIR}
    #Crow::Crow
)

message("Debug message: ${TGBOT_LIBRARY}")
target_link_libraries(executable 
    ${TGBOT_LIBRARY}
    ${headerFiles}
    ${sourceFiles} 
    ${JSONCPP_LIBRARY_DIR}/jsoncpp.lib
    Threads::Threads
    ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES} ${CURL_LIBRARIES}
)
```

So instead of looking for `..\lib\TgBot.lib`, CMake looks for `..\lib`. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: weird. From a cursory glance, I don't see why this would be happening. try re-running the configuration command. If that doesn't change anything, try also re-running it with a fresh variable cache using [`--fresh`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-fresh).

Comment: "The CMake file looks like this" - Please, provide the **exact** code. The one in the question post does not correspond to the error message, which tells about target named "executable" (the shown code has "exec" target).

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I updated CMake. It is now exactly as I use in my project

Comment: The path in the error message comes from the `CURL_LIBRARY` variable. From the view of `find_package(CURL)` this variable should contain the **library**, but you assign a **directory** to it. And the error message clearly describes that...